# Selenium webdriver js :Unexpected identifier js

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I tired alot but couldnot find the way to solve it.Error is some thing like :
unexpected identifier "js". Previously,something error like element cannot be found it was said so tried by putting Javascriptexecutor but also its not working.I even added wait time but also got some error.So,can we add time?

```
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var path = require('chromedriver').path;


var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(path).build();
chrome.setDefaultService(service);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
    .build();

    driver.get("https://www.keela.co");

    driver.getTitle().then(title => console.log(title));

    JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.linkText("Log In")).click();

        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);


        //waiting for  to load
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//input[@id='login-email']")).sendKeys("bandana@yopmail.com");

        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//input[@id='login-password']")).sendKeys("keela");

        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary']")).click();
```

Comment: "JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor) driver;" – that's not JavaScript syntax, it looks more like Java. Did you copy it off some Java tutorial?

Comment: not copied totally but I was facing problem at unable to locate element : {"method" :link text} .So,I had tried this it will solve or not and again I face error

Comment: JavascriptExecutor is Java language syntax

Comment: I had remove that JavascriptExecutor and had try but unable to locate element error was passed even though my given linktext is correct

Comment: may be you need to wait sometimes for the page/element to load.

Comment: any correct code for wait?